# Can't find snd.aloop

Tags: updates, sound, drivers, package, alsa

anand@anand2:/lib/modules/5.4.0-48-generic/kernel/sound/drivers$ ls
pcsp

-> I can't find any package for snd.aloop inside this directory,

anand@anand2:~$ uname -r
5.4.0-48-generic

-> Please Anyone Help me to solve this ?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1):

Type in the terminal

```
$ sudo apt install linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r)
$ sudo reboot
```

After the restart check does it work with this command:

```
modprobe snd-aloop
```